# Mozilla does not interpret the HTML contained in my xml

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I don't speak English very well because I'm french so sorry if I make mistakes.
I have this code :

```
<xsl:when test="$PARAM=1">
        <xsl:if test="LabelType=0 or LabelType=1 or LabelType=2 or LabelType=3 or LabelType=4 or LabelType=5 or LabelType=9 or LabelType=11 or LabelType=99 or LabelType=98 or LabelType=15 or LabelType=14" >
          <div class="sst">
            <table style="font-size: 12px">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=1">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/stethoscope-icon.png" alt="Consultation" />
                      Consultation
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=2">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/Pen-icon.png" alt="Certificat" />
                      Certificat
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=3">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/Pen-3-icon.png" alt="Demande" />
                      Demande
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=4">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/pill-icon.png" alt="Prescription" />
                      Prescription
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=5">
                      <img src="Images/options-icon2.png" alt="Formulaire" />
                      Formulaire
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=8">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/Bio-hazard-icon.png" alt="Vaccin" />
                      Vaccin
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=9">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/Coins-icon.png" alt="Reglement" />
                      Reglement
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=10">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/Paper-Clip-icon.png" alt="Binary" />
                      Binary
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=11">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/BPink.png" alt="Grossesse" />
                      Grossesse
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=15">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/stethoscope-icon.png" alt="Planche" />
                      Planche
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=14">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/stethoscope-icon.png" alt="Audio" />
                      Audio
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=99">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/twitter-bulb-icon.png" alt="Conclusion" />
                      Conclusion
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LabelType=98">
                      <img src="Images/Atcd/You-make-me-hurt-icon.png" alt="A.T." />
                      A.T.
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:if test="LabelType != 0">
                        <img src="Images/Atcd/Medical-invoice-information-icon.png" alt="Inconnu" />
                        Inconnu <xsl:value-of select="LabelType"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <xsl:if test="Texte1">
            <xsl:if test="Title1">
              <div class="sst2">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Title1"/>
              </div>
            </xsl:if>
            <div class="stx">
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Texte1"/>
            </div>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="LabelType!=5 and LabelType!=15 and LabelType!=14">
            <xsl:if test="Texte2">
              <xsl:if test="Title2">
                <div class="sst2">
                  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Title2"/>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>
              <div class="stx">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Texte2"/>
              </div>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="LabelType!=15 and LabelType!=14">
            <xsl:if test="Texte3">
              <xsl:if test="Title3">
                <div class="sst2">
                  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Title3"/>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>
              <div class="stx">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Texte3"/>
              </div>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="LabelType!=15 and LabelType!=14">
            <xsl:if test="Texte4">
              <xsl:if test="Title4">
                <div class="sst2">
                  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Title4"/>
                </div>
              </xsl:if>
              <div class="stx">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="Texte4"/>
              </div>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Suivis">
            <xsl:with-param name="viewtype" select="$viewtype" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
```

This genarate a lot of "div" and it works very good on chrome and IE but in Mozilla disable-output-escaping doesn't work and I have some blocks of HTML code not interpreted. I tryied a lot of things but any solutions work. In Javascript I can take the contents of a div and put it back in an other div with InnerHTML but it works only for one div not for all div. I think it's because it's a loop when and I can't call multiple div by the same id. So can you help me please ? I'm blocked since one week.

XML :

```
<Document>
<LabelType>4</LabelType>
<Texte1>&lt;div&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit&quot;&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;ZOLPIDEM ALMUS 10 mg Cpr pell séc Plq/14&lt;/STRONG&gt;&lt;/span&gt; &lt;span style=&quot;font-family: inherit; color:#0000ff; font-size: inherit;&quot;&gt;(2 boîtes)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;Prendre un comprimé au coucher, pendant un  mois &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;</Texte1>
</Document>
```

Output :

```
<div><span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit"><STRONG>ZOLPIDEM ALMUS 10 mg Cpr pell séc Plq/14</STRONG></span> <span style="font-family: inherit; color:#0000ff; font-size: inherit;">(2 boîtes)</span></div><div style="font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit"><div>Prendre un comprimé au coucher, pendant un mois </div></div><div>&nbsp;</div>
```

What I want :

ZOLPIDEM ALMUS 10 mg Cpr pell séc Plq/14 (2 boîtes)
Prendre un comprimé au coucher, pendant un mois

Comment: Have you validated the xsl?

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: Find an XSL validator and use it?

Comment: No need. My xsl works in Chrome and IE, the problem is in Mozilla

Comment: It is known and documented https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#Can_I_do_disable-output-escaping.3F that `disable-output-escaping` is not supported in Mozilla browsers so if you need that you will have to perform the transformation server-side. If you are trying to use a Javascript workaround then please show minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, Javascript, HTML you want and HTML you get, allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I edited the post with informations you wanted

Comment: Is it an option to change the XML input, so that the embedded XHTML is presented literally therein, instead of in its escaped form?

Comment: No I can't change the XML input because I receive it like that :/

Comment: Even though you (the server, I suppose you mean) receive the XML like that from some source, that does not necessarily mean you need to relay it to the client in the same form.  Is there something preventing you from pre-processing it on the server side to perform the transformation to *bona fide* embedded XHTML elements?

Comment: I'm just on the client side. My mission is get in shape (I don't know if it's correct) the XML with HTML,CSS and Javascript only. I have no information about the server side. I repeat, my code works on IE and chrome I just want Mozilla to interprate the HTML code contain in XML :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all of you to have trying to help me. I found the solution :

```
function decode() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { 
    var div = divs[i];
    if (div.className == "stx") {
      div.innerHTML = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it will help other peoples. Goodbye :)

Answer (score 0):

Relying on `disable-output-escaping` is usually the worst possible alternative.  You should do so only when there are no others.  The XSLT spec actually says that:

> An XSLT processor will only be able to disable output escaping if it controls how the result tree is output. This may not always be the case. For example, the result tree may be used as the source tree for another XSLT transformation instead of being output.An XSLT processor is not required to support disabling output escaping.  [...]
>
> Since disabling output escaping may not work with all XSLT processors and can result in XML that is not well-formed, **it should be used only when there is no alternative**.

(XSLT 1.0 recommendation, section 16.4; emphasis added)

If you think about it, disabling output escaping for a task such as yours assumes a processing model in which the serialized output of the transformation is re-parsed.  Only in that way could text having the form of HTML be transformed into actual HTML elements in XSLT's data model.  When you are performing the transformation inside a browser, however, it seems entirely plausible to me that the browser won't actually *output* the result at all, much less re-parse it, because the transformation result is already a document that it can, in principle, use as-is.

Ultimately, then, Firefox's reported behavior with the given input is fully permitted by the relevant specifications.  That other browsers behave differently is not a counter-indication (and the behavior you describe for them is also permitted).  It seems unlikely that any approach depending on `disable-output-escaping` -- or more generally on the browser re-parsing the XSLT output -- will meet your needs.

Essentially, what you would need to do is *parse* the string values of some of your input elements as HTML (or XHTML) to get a node-set or result-tree fragment to work with (assuming XSLT 1.0).  Questions along those lines have been asked here many times, and all that offer any solution other than `disable-output-escaping` have reached that conclusion.  Among those that offer specific variations are:

- [xslt convert xml string in xml elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789590/xslt-convert-xml-string-in-xml-elements)

  - the second answer demonstrates building a mini XML parser in XSLT
- [Two phase XSLT transformation converting string to XML first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896703/two-phase-xslt-transformation-converting-string-to-xml-first)

  - The question was edited to present a solution using msxml and `XmlDocument.loadXml()` (this is presumably not directly useful to you)
  - The second answer demonstrates using an external XML parser, in this case SAXON, which provides a `parse()` function accessible to the stylesheet (this relies on SAXON being available on the client, which may not be a safe assumption for you)

Ultimately, this would be a lot easier for you, and probably more portable and robust, if you could persuade whoever controls the form of the input XML to provide the embedded HTML as actual XHTML fragments rather than text.  If indeed that is not an option then you have my sympathy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to do what I want with your solutions and I will come back (probably tomorrow) here if I have other questions or if it's doesn't works